# Change filename during upload

Tags: attachments, sanitization

I check the below answer to rename files during upload and tries to change it to something like postid_originalfilename.jpg but failed. Any help?

```
function make_filename_hash($filename) {
$info = pathinfo($filename);
$ext  = empty($info['extension']) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
$name = basename($filename, $ext);
return md5($name) . $ext;
}
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'make_filename_hash', 10);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586284/rename-files-on-upload-in-wordpress-3-4-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the above `sanitize_file_name` filter, you could try this:

```
function make_filename_hash($filename) {

    if( isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ) {
        $post_id =  (int)$_REQUEST['post_id'];
    }else{
        $post_id=0;
    }

    $info = pathinfo($filename);
    $ext  = empty($info['extension']) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = basename($filename, $ext);

    if($post_id>0){
        return $post_id."_".$name . $ext;
    }else{
        return $name . $ext;
    }
}
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'make_filename_hash', 10);
```

where for example `image.jpg` is changed to `123_image.jpg` where 123 is the parent post id.

Comment: That's awesome and works like a charm! Thank you very much for the quick reply, it's really helpful!